# How can I access and push data into LSB of Mp3 frame?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, frame, steganography

I want to access mp3 frame and push my data into Least Significant Bit of that frame.

My project is about steganography for mp3 file using LSB method using C# language. LSB in this case is bit (bits) that has least impact on the output sound of mp3 file. I have a binary array of data that will embed into mp3 file using LSB method.

I want to know how can I access each frame of mp3 file (carrier file) then embed my data (in binary array) into each frame of mp3 file.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What do you know and don't know about what you want to do so far? Where are you stuck? What language? Just saying you want X and exhibiting no understanding on the issue makes it look like you want us to do everything for you. The `lsb` tag refers to something different and not to least significant bits. You should remove that and probably add a tag of language of interest (if it's targetting a specific one).

Comment: I'm sorry because this is the first time I raise a question! I'll explain it more clearly. My project is about steganography for mp3 file using LSB method using C# language. LSB in this case is bit (bits) that has least impact on the output sound of mp3 file. I have a binary array of data that will embed into mp3 file using LSB method. what I want is know how can I access each frame of mp3 file (carrier file) then embed my data (in binary array) into each frame of mp3 file.

Comment: To read the frames, you'll either need a library which reads audio files, or you'll need to understand the mp3 file structure itself so you can write your own code to read the header and the frames. What you call lsb method isn't objective, though most people would take that to mean embed 1 bit per byte of the carrier file sequentially. Please clarify exactly what you're aiming to do and what you have difficulty with. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28363194/edit) your question and add all of this information there. Don't forget to remove the `lsb` tag and add `c#`.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three other questions on SO that address this, poorly.  The only lead I can find is [MP3Stego](http://www.petitcolas.net/steganography/mp3stego/), but I can't immediately find the stego bitrate it supports.

There are a few options for doing this that I can think of, but the simplest is to compress, checksum, encrypt, modulate (repetition & ECC/parity), and insert the hidden data into the raw PCM data before encoding with MP3.  You only have to make sure enough survives encoding to be decodeable, which can be achieved through careful selection of encoder settings (decoders must follow the spec, so selection of decoder doesn't matter as much).

To be able to truly use MP3 to hide data, you'll have to become intimately familiar with the codec's design and how you can leverage the different stages to encode inaudible "errors" that can be used to store stego bits.

Comment: Another approach might be to build an layer III codec that occasionally - at locations in the output bitstream known to transmitter and receiver - makes encoding decisions based on a stream of data to be hidden rather than the usual psycho-acoutic model (e.g. whether a sub-band is considered to be masked, and therefore discarded).  For sure, the LSB of just about any audio stream will be quantised away just about all of the time, so that's never going to work.

Comment: That's absolutely correct.  One might consider putting all the steps of my initial idea into the encoder itself and have the encoder chose the VBR rate of each frame based on successful transmission of the stego data...  That would probably work, but is more complicated.  Going any further (tweaking the codec's logic directly) may give even greater bandwidth & hiding, but would be exceedingly difficult to describe in a SO answer...

Comment: Yes. I suspect the effort is pretty much equivalent to developing an MP3 encoder.   Not exactly trivial.